# Determining flash component has loaded

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, browser

I have an HTML page containing a flash file,
I need to write code in javascript that would execute once the flash file is loaded.
(its actually the code to overide the `__flash__removeCallback` to solve the famous line:52 bug refer: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-529)

The actual solution for the bug is doing so on window.onUnload. But this is not possible in my cases since the flash component is in an iframe and the window.onUnload is never fired at all.

For the code to not display an error, i need to track event when the flash file has finished loading on screen.

does any one here have a solution to track down when the flash file has completed loading

**OR**

Any other solution for the bug that does not involve tracking window.onUnload ?

Comment: I do not have access to the flash file source, so suggesting an External callback would probably not be helpful,
besides, its callbacks that are actually causing the problem.

My object,embed tag have ids,type, name too, still the error is caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you embed the flash file with [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject), you can used [embedSWF](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrlStr,_replaceElemIdStr,_widthStr,_height)'s "callbackFn" parameter which is called when the file is loaded.

Comment: The content of the flash (object tag + embedded tag) is returned from the server as a string. so the embedding mentioned above is not possible.

Besides that, using a Third party component in our system may not be approved.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using an iframe. Move the inner html of the iframe to a div element. Then you will probably be able to catch the event.

Comment: i know that.
If there is no iframe, the problem solution is already given, but i do not have an option here as this is a seperate module in our project and hence it needs to be incorporated in an iframe.
solution is not feasible.